# How to select any input matching a list of classes?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

This code works as I need:

```
$('input[class="plus"], input[class="minus"]').mousedown(function () {       
        //..doing something
    });
```

---

What I wanted is something like:

```
$('input[class="plus minus"]').mousedown(function () {            
        //..doing something
    });
```

or like:

```
$('input[class="plus"][class="minus"]').mousedown(function () {            
        //..doing something
    });
```

The selector should choose any input, having either `plus` class or `minus`.

There must be some other syntax, but I don't know one.

Comment: y cant u use $('.plus minus').mouse

Comment: ...or $('input.plus, input.minus')

Comment: @ArunKillu: No, that would look for elements with the **tag** `minus` that were descendants of elements with the class `plus`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder ok ,10x for that info.

Comment: +1 to every answer...They all seemed to give me some useable thoughts on jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend:

```
$('input.plus, input.minus').mousedown(function () {            
    //..doing something
});
```

...so that other classes on the inputs don't make you skip them. If you use the attribute equals selector (your `input[class="plus"]`), it will only match if the **only** class on the `input` is `"plus"`. So it would match `<input class="plus">` but not `<input class="plus foo">`. Normally you want the flexibility of having other classes on the element.

Alternately, you *could* do this:

```
$('input').filter('.plus, .minus').mousedown(...);
```

...but it would be likely to be less efficient: First it would make jQuery look up *all* `input` elements, and then separately filter the result to just the ones with those classes. So I wouldn't recommend it.

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax is using a comma to separate the selectors like you point out, but the selectors should be written like this:

```
$('input.plus, input.minus').mousedown(function () {       
    //..doing something
});
```

As a final alternative you can use `.add`:

```
$('input.plus')
    .add($('input.minus'))
    // possibly add more elements here
    .mouseover(...);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('input.plus, input.minus').mousedown(function () {       
    //..doing something
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I would go for binding

```
$onInputMouseDown = function() {
    ....
}

$(".plus").bind("mousedown",$onInputMouseDown);
$(".minus").bind("mousedown",$onInputMouseDown);
```

Comment: +1 For I am only starting to study jquery, I didn't know about this. I will surely give it a try one day

Comment: The good part is that you can track better your functions. If something goes wrong, you don't need to search for an event x on component y, but rather, for a function on your code. I like it pretty much